# sql server 2008 enable sa account

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sa

I logged into SQL Server 2008 via SQL Server Management Studio using Windows admin account. When I run the command (`ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE`)  I get the following error.

> Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

You account doesn't have permissions. It isn't sysadmin.

[CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) requires

> Requires CREATE DATABASE, CREATE ANY DATABASE, or ALTER ANY DATABASE permission.

This is (legacy [SQL Server 2000 lingo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175892.aspx)):

- sysadmin
- dbcreator

If the account is "end user" consider wrapping the call in a stored procedure to hide the permissiosn escalation

Edit, after question update

sa is always sa; you can't disable it as such

You need to grant some permissions to the Windows account using [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advices in this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

**EDIT**: The whole question changed!

Comment: Of course, It should be used to check whether the problem arises from insufficient permissions. This is obvious that you must not grant sysadmin rights to any other user, unless you have a good reason.